# Multiple Vlookup or IF condition?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two datafile,

one file consisting of data such as

```
Column A     Column B     Column C (describes column B)
Germany       Munich       City 
Munich        Germany      Country
Germany       Berlin       Capital
France        Paris        Capital
Paris         France       Country
Spain         Barcelona    City
Spain         Madrid       Capital
Italy         Rome         Capital
```

Another data set as,

```
Column A
France
Paris
Germany
Munich
Italy
Rome
Spain
Madrid
Barcelona
```

I would like to get a new column in data set 2, which says if the date in the next line is a city or a capital.

Such as,

```
Column A     Column B  
Germany      Capital - Berlin, City - Munich
Munich       Munich - Country
France       Capital - Paris
Spain        Barcelona - City and Madrid- Capital   
.
. 
.
```

Comment: why is Munich in the 2nd data set? It doesn't seem to fit.  Also, are you looking for a formula solution or a VBA solution?  I'm not sure that you can get a formula to do a loop through and then concatenate results (holds breath and hoping that XL Xperts don't come around and prove me wrong).  Also (2): column B of the 2nd data set has inconsistent formatting and pattern of display...is that intentional?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. You want to know what is the line after in your Column A (Capital or City). But Italy is missing in your example and you have the line `Munich Munich - Country`. If you reexplain what you exactly need we can tell you which way to go (Excel or VBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TextJoin as an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(E1=$A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8 & " - " & $C$1:$C$8,""))
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Crtl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel

[image]

---

To make the formula more dynamic:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(E1=$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A)) & " - " & $C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),""))
```

This will now grow(or shrink) the effective references to only the data set.  As more lines are added it will reference the new items also without any unneeded iterations.

---

If one does not have Office 365 Excel we can split the output into different cells with.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)) &" - " & $C$1:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A))=$E1),COLUMN(
```

Put this in the upper left cell then copy over and down.

[image]

---

If one must have the output in the same cell and does not have TEXTJOIN, use this code as a UDF and the same TEXTJOIN formula above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Before I can even answer your question:

> I'm gonna pretend that the "`Muninch`" in the 2nd row of your provided
>   data is just an error on your part.

If not, then your question is impossible to answer, because Excel has no inbuilt logic of recognizing what string is a country and city.

You can technically check, if it's contained within the Country range of the second data table and if not, we can presume it is a city, but do us all and more importantly yourself a favour and do sort your data properly!

What I'm trying to say is, each column needs to contain unique data to their respective type:

```
 Country      City       Type
 -------      ----       -----
 Italy        Milan      City
 Italy        Rome       Capital
 Germany      Munich     City
 Amsterdam    Amsterdam  Capital   // < A BIG NO-NO !!!
```

If your answer to that is, but *"but I have them in one column!"* then I simply recommend you to scrap that data and transcribe it manually, because you'll lose more time trying to think up an algorithm of detecting  when the data is Country or City, than if you simply sorted that data manually.

Furthermore, **conflicting data structure / types should be avoided at all costs**, be it in programming, databases, data-tables or pretty much anything you can think of.

As the age-old saying goes, **you  don't mix apples with oranges**

---

### Now that we got our groceries sorted:

I can't really think of an efficient approach to achieve <s>via formulas</s> via `VLOOKUP`
We need to take a different approach a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) approach:

What we aim to do is:

1. Loop through our second data-table consisting of unique countries
2. Use `find` operation on our main data-table to extract data
3. Append it to adjacent column of our table in Step 1.
4. Celebrate <sup>yay <sup>we did it..!</sup></sup>

> Presuming the big data table is in `Sheet1` and the countries
>   data-table in `Sheet2`

[image]    [image]

We achieve that accordingly:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub loop_through_countries()
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   Dim lr1 As Long ' last active row in sht1
   Dim lr2 As Long ' last active row in sht2
   Dim searchrange As Range 'big data table
   Dim cell As Range ' cell to loop through countries table
   Dim temp As Range ' temp to hold result of find operation
   Dim result As String ' storing result

   lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).Copy ' we add extra column, as we need data to "check off"
   ws1.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert ' basically, we need to remove data _ 
                                         from array upon checking for it
   ws1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' otherwise we'd be stuck in endless loop

   Set searchrange = ws1.Range("B2:B" & lr1)

   For Each cell In ws2.Range("A2:A" & lr2) ' for country table

      Set temp = searchrange.Find(cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
      If Not temp Is Nothing Then 'if found
         Do Until temp Is Nothing
             If result = "" Then ' no comma in result if it's first argument
                result = temp.Offset(0, 1) + " - " + temp.Offset(0, 2)
             Else
                result = result + ", " + temp.Offset(0, 1) + " - " + temp.Offset(0, 2)
             End If

             temp = "Checked"
             Set temp = searchrange.FindNext(temp)
         Loop

       Else
          cell.Offset(0, 1) = "No matches found!"
       End If

       cell.Offset(0, 1) = result   '  print result to adjacant column

       ' and we need to reseult our result and temp
       Set temp = Nothing
       result = ""

    Next cell

    ws1.Range("B1").EntireColumn.delete ' and we delete the extra helping column

End Sub
```

---

### Let's see if it bears some fruit:

Okay, enough with the fruit puns already!!
Bottom line is, although this was bit complicated, that it works:

[image]

*If you have any questions, please let me know, I'd be happy to explain*

---

> **EDIT:** Damn @ScottCraner and his magical formulas. Though to be fair, **the code I provided will work with any dynamic range, while
>    the formula needs to be adjusted manually**, so there is some use to
>    the code nonetheless.
>
> Though I have to say, it is rather comic he
>    managed to write my ~hundred lines of code in 1 line. 
>   Upvoted his answer for simplicity, but choose whatever you see fit.

Comment: I can make my formula more dynamic, grow or shrink the dataset with the data.

Comment: See my edit.  I added the dynamic references.  Now no need to change the formula as the dataset grows.

Comment: @ScottCraner Damn, way to go making my answer obsolete! :( - *i jest, nice answer, upvoted already though*